# Boto randomly connecting to different regions for S3 transfers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have several S3 buckets containing a total of 40 TB of data across 761 million objects.  I undertook a project to copy these objects to EBS storage.  To my knowledge, all buckets were created in us-east-1.  I know for certain that all of the EC2 instances used for the export to EBS were within us-east-1.

The problem is that the AWS bill for last month included a pretty hefty charge for inter-regional data transfer.  I'd like to know how this is possible?

The transfer used a pretty simple Python script with Boto to connect to S3 and download the contents of each object.  I suspect that the fact that the bucket names were composed of uppercase letters might have been a contributing factor (I had to specify `OrdinaryCallingFormat()`), but I don't know this for sure.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, a bucket with uppercase characters in it's name can only exist in the *classic* S3 region (i.e. us-east-1).  Did all of your bucket names contain uppercase characters?  Do the buckets still exist?  If so, you could double check their location like this:

```
import boto
c = boto.connect_s3()
for bucket in c.get_all_buckets():
    print(bucket.name, bucket.get_location())
```

If the bucket is located anywhere other than the `us-east-1` region, you will see the location printed next to it's name.  Otherwise, it will be blank.

If all of the buckets are in the `us-east-1` region and you are 100% certain that all of the EC2 instances were also in `us-east-1` and that all of the EBS volumes you created were also in the `us-east-1` region than I have no explanation for why you would have seen inter-regional traffic charges on your bill.  I do not believe that boto randomly connects to different regions.  It might be worth asking AWS about that.  There probably is a legitimate reason but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: Mitch, the problem ended up being an internal billing error at AWS.  They're working to correct it.  Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being an internal billing error at AWS and was not related to either S3 or Boto.